# Get response in catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am sending `data` and `errors` from my graphql endpoint (schema is made in `Graphene`). The way I am querying is using `client.query` method (provided as a prop when I use `withApollo` HOC).

The way I am doing is this:

```
    let result = this.props.client.query({
        query: query,
        variables: {},
        fetchPolicy: this.state.fetchPolicy
        })
        .then(result => this.handle_data(result.data))
        .catch((e) => {
            alert("Hello"+e);
        });
```

When some error occurs in server (due to some wrong query), I am sending `data` as `null` and `errors` set with actual error message. Then here `catch` block gets executed. The value of `e` is not the `errors` I sent from my server. How can I get the server response that I sent in `catch` block (like we are getting in `then` block)?

Comment: I assume wrong query will result in a business exception but not server exception.Business exception may not be caught in catch block

Comment: @brk `result = schema.execute(query)` will automatically populate `result.data` and `result.errors`. I checked it as well. So this means response fetched will be containing both `data` and `errors`. In client, the catch block is executed. Can I somehow get my response object in catch block?

Comment: Where is the error being thrown? In client.query()? If so, then this is the error thrown by Apollo client, and this only contains the error and no data, according to the API (http://dev.apollodata.com/core/apollo-client-api.html#ApolloClient\.query)

Comment: @FinbarrO'B yes! you are correct. Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score -1):

use withApollo then add errorPolicy: 'ignore' on your config, like this:

```
const result = await client.query({
      query: getQuery(fieldArgs),
      variables: { filters: [...filters] },
      errorPolicy: 'ignore',
    });
```